# Is Couchdb limited to a single core or not?

Tags: couchdb

Can Couchdb  saturate all cores on a multi-core machine for read/write operations like MongoDB ( in MOngoDB all core used only for read operations ) or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Like any other erlang application couchdb utilizes all the cores available in your machine.

Here is a screen shot for my couch beam process. As you can see it is happily running on both the cores (I have a two core machine)

[image]

Couchdb however spwans many process and not all of them are multicore. For example a couchjs process that is spawned for building views is single core. However there is a couchjs process for every design_doc which essentially means that you can build multiple views together and they will be distributed across the cores.

To answer your question both read and write are multicore operations but view building is not.